# Expand Data when linked with foreign keys

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using Microsft SQL Server 2012 Management Studio, I have two tables with linked columns via primary / foreign keys.

When I run

```
SELECT * FROM tblCars
```

you get the results of the table. How can I get the little plus signs to show so I can expand the rows and see the linked data from the other table? I've attached a picture showing the plus signs. I added them in red.

[image]

Thanks!
Michael

Comment: I wasnt aware that this was even possible! Where have you seen this?

Comment: According to our lecturer you could do it in 2008, but its quite possible that he's confusing programs.. :/

Comment: Are you possibly confusing running a query with viewing the table via the Object Browser in management studio?

Comment: ***what*** other table? You're not mentioning anything, nor is your select fetching data from another table.....

Comment: Can you do it with the Object Browser? 

The other table is people and it is linked via a foreign key. How would I fetch data from both tables?

Comment: @Michael You can view the foreign keys via the object browser. If you want to view tha data from multiple tables you are going to need to write an sql query with joins. But this wont display it was you have described above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that as far as I know and in any ordinalry sized real buisiness database, you wouldn't want to. That could end up pulling miilions of records! You see the data by running a SQL statement with a join. And since you are learning use an explicit join not an implicit one and get out of the habit of writing select *.

A sample query would be something like:

```
select a.carname, b.partname
from cars a
join parts b on a.carid = b.carid
```